# How can I strip out the string like � in php?

Tags: php, string, character-encoding, escaping, strip

How can I vanish out the odd string like � in php?

I already use like html_entity_decode php function but it's still not works.

Comment: This is an encoding problem. Do you have a `<meta charset` that is consistent with what your server sends?

Comment: This is usually caused by mixed character encodings. Make sure the page's character encoding is the same as the server.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder yes, i already use <meta charset and still not works...

Comment: fix the problem not the symptoms

Comment: What encoding are you sending in the `meta` tag? Does it match the encoding of the content you are sending?

Comment: It may be your file encoding, do you use a IDE (Netbeans, Eclipse, Dreamweaver, Zend Studio, etc)?

Comment: FYI, the character `'�'` is U+FFEF, "REPLACEMENT CHARACTER".

Comment: posting some relevant codes might help

Comment: I use utf-8 encoding. <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> and it's not solution in this case. any trick to vanish that odd ?

Comment: If you are using UTF8 then the data source is not using UTF8. Check your data source for which character encoding it is using (or Collation if it is MySQL) and then adjust your `<meta>` tag to match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add these line in your db config file.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);
mysql_select_db("db_name", $con);


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />
```

Comment: You might want to consider upgrading to PDO -- the old style SQL functions are horribly insecure.  Bound statements are not only quicker and more efficient, but they transparently quarantine inputs so you don't have to worry about injection attacks.  Little Bobby 'Drop Tables' loves playing games with old-style SQL commands.

Answer (score 1):

� isn't just one symbol -- it's the symbol used to replace a symbol that your browser can't make sense of.  Usually this is caused by encoding issues -- you set the wrong encoding, or someone is using a symbol from a different encoding.

You can't just magically strip it out, because it isn't just one character.  Simply put, encoding is one place where you can't just wave a magic wand -- you have to decide on an encoding, and then enforce it.

If you're taking user input, I honestly don't have any clue how to help with the issue.  You can check for common causes (curly quotes and dashes **as distinct from hyphens** are where I run into this the most), and force a manual replace on them, but if a user wants to enter in a badly-encoded character, there's not a lot you can do.

Comment: +1 because you mentioned "you have to decide on an encoding, and then enforce it." you are absolutely right about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `<meta charset` to iso-8859-1 like

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If your content is in ANSI encoding use

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

you can check the encoding of your files using a editor like ( NOTEPAD ++ )